# C get fractional value as int

Tags: c, floating-point, int

I'm trying to get the value of the fractional part of a number. I need the number as an integer however.

```
float x = 12.345; // eventually not hard-coded
int whole = (int)x;
int frac = (x - (float)whole); // this gives 0.345 - expected
```

`x` may be/have any length of decimal places. I need (in my example) 345 stored in `frac`

I'm thinking I should store the value as a string/char[] and then manipulate the values...

Q: How can I get the fractional value of a fractional number stored as int?

Comment: What should be the result for `12.1` and `12.001`. Should they both be `1`?

Comment: For a fixed number of 3 decimals: multiply by 1000 and use `%`.

Comment: Note that because of the nature of floating point, for `float x = 0.3` you might get 299.

Comment: ... multiply by 1000, `round` to the nearest `int`, and use `%`

Comment: To get the fractional part you might want to look into the `modf()` family of functions. And getting "any length of decimal places" without having an idea of the number of significant digits doesn't make sense to me (as @Barmar's question suggests).  Can you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: How can I get the fractional value of a fractional number stored as int?

Use `modff()` to break a `float` into  whole number and fractional parts. [@Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957815/c-get-fractional-value-as-int/48959341?noredirect=1#comment84922675_48957815)

> The `modf` functions break ... into integral and fractional parts,

```
#include <math.h>
float x = 12.345;
float whole;
float frac = modff(x, &whole);
```

---

> The `lrint` and `llrint` functions round their argument to the nearest integer value, rounding according to the current rounding direction.

Scale the fractional part and round.

```
int i = lrintf(frac * 1000);
```

---

Using `int whole = (int)x;` is *undefined behavior* when `x` is much outside the `int` range.

Other approaches that multiple `x` by 1000 first may incur rounding inaccuracies or may overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick routine that has what you are looking for. If you need to change the number of digits past the decimal then change the 3 in the .3f in the first printf to match the digits. otherwise you will either see the result multiplied by a multiple of 10 or stripped.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ for more formatting options.

I also allocated 10 bytes for the number instead of 6 to lower the chances of error should you decide to use a larger number.

The "return 0" simply means normal exit. This has been tested in GCC 4.3.3. for linux and works with no warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  float x = 12.345; // your number
  char num[10];     // allocate 10 bytes to store number.
  sprintf(num,"%0.3f",x); //Format number to string with 3 digits past decimal max
  char* frac=strchr(num,(int)'.'); //Find decimal point
  if (frac){ //If decimal found then...
    frac++;    //advance character pointer so we start at wanted number
    printf("%s\n",frac); //as a test, print it as a string
    long int result=strtol(frac,NULL,10); //convert string to long integer
    printf("%ld\n",result); //and print again
  }
  return 0;
}
```